# Internet Explorer CSS Problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This [page](http://a.accioly.7rtc.com/p/tecnologia.html) is being rendered incorrectly by IE 9 (and probably older versions too). The right menu is floating to the bottom of the page. Firefox, Chrome and Safari are rendering it correctly. Other pages in the blog are also being rendered fine by all browsers. I already tried to fire IE 9 Developer Tools (F12) and reduce the width of some divs (such as #main and .columns-inner)... no lucky with this approach, even with extra space the right menu is still rendered at the bottom. So I figure that the problem is in the Blogger auto-generated tags / css for the page content (which I am able to modify). Any CSS gurus out there can point what is wrong?

Cheers,

Comment: WOW that's a lot of `div`'s... Not surprising it's not rendered correctly everywhere. Why make it so hard? Cut back on the divs! `float` and clearfix are your friends!

Comment: Hehehe. To be fair, the layout was addapted from the original Picture Windows and most of the content was made with the Blogger WYSIWYG editor. This is the first compatibility problem I'm having, so the tool did a nice job.

Comment: It's not a difficult layout. If I were you, I'd start over with simpler HTML. Simpler HTML means (usually) simpler CSS. Simpler both means less error-prone.

Comment: I figured, but this is really something out of my league (I'm a server side developer with only basic knowledge of CSS / HTML). Guess this will not be as simples as I thought... I really which there would be a simple property that I could replace to make it work (since it is working correctly in every other page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The page has 104 validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fa.accioly.7rtc.com%2Fp%2Ftecnologia.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) — I’d start by fixing those if I were you.

Comment: Wow. Most are escaping problems but some may be the cause. Guess I will need to hire someone to dig into this lol.

Comment: @Anthony: actually, once you start knocking them off, they can disappear pretty quickly. A lot of them will be instances of the same issue which you can fix with a find-and-replace, others will be well-formedness errors that, when you fix them, make other reported errors not be errors any more.

Answer (score 4):

You have this line in your `<head>`, which is causing IE9 to render the page in IE7 mode:

`<META content=IE=EmulateIE7 http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible>`

If you remove this, it renders fine in IE8 and IE9.  It still renders poorly in IE7, though.

**Edit:**

In response to your comment, I am able to replicate the issue with the background no longer being opaque.  After some investigation, there is a particular script file being loaded:

http://www.blogger.com/static/v1/jsbin/938506610-ieretrofit.js

If you remove the `<meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>` on line 4 of the source, and you remove the `ieretrofit.js` file from line 1471 of the source, the page should render correctly in IE9.

Since the ieretrofit.js file appears to be generated by Google, you might want to ask them about it.  If you would like to disable it JUST for IE9, and allow it to continue for IE8 and below, you should take a closer look at line 1471 of the source.  Here is a snippet (it's quite long, this starts around character #2275):

```
'\74!--[if IE]\76\74script
```

The !--[if IE] there is part of an [IE conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can change that snippet like so, and it will still target IE8 and below, without affecting IE9:

```
'\74!--[if lte IE 8]\76\74script
```

Let me know if you have any further issues!

Comment: I tried removing it, but the window loses it's transparent aspect and renders in black :(.

Comment: Chris, just asked a question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774618/disabling-ieretrofit-js-on-blogger

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly it is because the [page is invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://a.accioly.7rtc.com/p/tecnologia.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Also, I really would think about starting again with this page as it is overly complex markup.

Comment: Really nobody and no browser cares if a page is 'valid'. 99% of the web's pages aren't 'valid'. Who cares about W3C's validity!?

Comment: @Rudie: different browsers render invalid pages in different ways. The first thing you do when one browser is acting up is make sure you’ve got your HTML right. (We’re using “validity” to mean both “valid” and “well-formed”.) Then you know that you’re encountering a browser bug.

Comment: Too bad non of the browsers follow the w3c's validator standards completely =) Valid is nice (always), but never a must. I don't try anymore. Good debugging tool though!

Comment: @Rudie: writing valid code isn’t much effort. To me, the validator is a thing that can show me a basic subset of the mistakes I make, leaving me to concentrate my efforts on the really tricky mistakes I make. In the OP’s instance, fixing some validation errors fixed his problem.

Comment: Fair enough =) 104 might be much. I usually have a few though, and none of the browsers care. Just saying that _"Almost certainly it is because the page is invalid"_ is a little/lot shortsighted.

Comment: Hence it was _almost_. @Rudie - it is not short-sighted, it comes from experience. Invalid pages can have completely undefined rendering consequences in different browsers. It's nothing to do with following the w3c standards, it's more to do with what a browser does when there _is_ non-standard markup.

Answer (score 0):

Guys. Figured it out (with great help from andyb and Paul D.)
The validator  pointed to some unpaired `</div>` tags that I removed. Now it is working flawless.

Comment: good stuff — it’s better to indicate that by accepting andyb’s answer (click the tick next to it), rather than by adding another answer yourself. Glad we helped!