# Disabling ieretrofit.js on Blogger

Tags: javascript, css, html, blogger

[this script](http://www.blogger.com/static/v1/jsbin/938506610-ieretrofit.js) is giving me trouble in IE 9. From what I heard it was used to get rounded corners working on old IE versions. Now I don't need it anymore... And worse, it is forcing me to keep a `<META content=IE=EmulateIE7 http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible>` tag or the scripts messes my opaque windows. It [seems](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/blogger/thread?tid=782b516fbbd63f3c&hl=en) to be included automatically with the `<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>` tag. Anyone knows how to prevent it from being loaded?

Comment: What background troubles specifically?

Comment: the div with class container-inner goes from semitransparent to black.
It happens here: http://a.accioly.7rtc.com/

Comment: Try swapping the meta's content with `IE=8`. See what happens.

Comment: Also, I'm afraid fixing this issue will be like trying to eating a seven-course meal--you can't do this piece by piece. You have to plan it out on the whole or the little problems will never stop.

Comment: IE=8, or IE=9 results in black window.
Well, I disabled the script with a debbuger and everything is running smoothly. So I guess all I need is to disable the script.

Comment: Hm, It runs fine for me. It could just be your copy of IE. Run over to the library and see how it looks there.

Comment: I Tried from a different computer, also, other StackOverflow user confirmed the bug. See the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774048/internet-explorer-css-problem

Comment: I have that same `<b:include` line in my blogger, but I don't get the ieretrofit.js - I think this is something theme specific.

Comment: Yeah. This template have been adapted from Picture Window and Simple. But I couldn't find a reference to the script anywhere in blogger variables and other common places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured this one out.

By replacing

```
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
```

With

```
<meta expr:content='&quot;text/html; charset=&quot; + data:blog.encoding' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
<meta content='true' name='MSSmartTagsPreventParsing'/>
<meta content='blogger' name='generator'/>
<link expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;favicon.ico&quot;' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
<link expr:href='data:blog.url' rel='canonical'/>
<data:blog.feedLinks/>  
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
   <link href='http://www.blogger.com/openid-server.g' rel='openid.server'/>
</b:if>
```

Everything works as expected.

At least for my blog this produces the same header output than before (minus the two IE specific scripts and a third global script which I'm not sure about). I've run `diff` to be sure.

**Update 1**

If you want the non IE specific script, just add this after the Content-Type tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>(function() { var a=window;function c(b){this.t={};this.tick=function(b,i,d){d=d!=void 0?d:(new Date).getTime();this.t[b]=[d,i]};this.tick(&quot;start&quot;,null,b)}var e=new c;a.jstiming={Timer:c,load:e};try{var g=null;a.chrome&amp;&amp;a.chrome.csi&amp;&amp;(g=Math.floor(a.chrome.csi().pageT));g==null&amp;&amp;a.gtbExternal&amp;&amp;(g=a.gtbExternal.pageT());g==null&amp;&amp;a.external&amp;&amp;(g=a.external.pageT);g&amp;&amp;(a.jstiming.pt=g)}catch(h){};a.tickAboveFold=function(b){var f=0;if(b.offsetParent){do f+=b.offsetTop;while(b=b.offsetParent)}b=f;b&lt;=750&amp;&amp;a.jstiming.load.tick(&quot;aft&quot;)};var j=!1;function k(){j||(j=!0,a.jstiming.load.tick(&quot;firstScrollTime&quot;))}a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener(&quot;scroll&quot;,k,!1):a.attachEvent(&quot;onscroll&quot;,k);
 })();</script>
```

**Update 2**

This also removes the generated `<link rel="image_src">`. I just hardcoded an image.