# IE9 Javascript error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

The tag cloud of [my blog](http://a.accioly.7rtc.com/) isn't rendering correctly with IE 9.
The problem seems to be around those lines of code:

```
var fs = s(minFontSize,maxFontSize,ts[t]-ta,tz);
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.style.fontSize = fs+'px';
```

The strange thing is that everything works fine if I remove the compatibility tag:

```
<meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```

But I can't do that or my opaque window turns black because of another script (See [Disabling ieretrofit.js on Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774618/disabling-ieretrofit-js-on-blogger)).

Can anyone help me to fix that?

ps: Since it isn't working I've hiden the tag cloud with the following JQuery snipet (lame, I know).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($.browser.msie ) {
    $("#Label1").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
The `s` method sometimes returned `NaN` (that for some reason only caused trouble with IE in compatibility mode).
I fixed it with the `isNaN` method like this:

```
if (!isNaN(fs)) {
  li.style.fontSize = fs+'px';
 }
```

And one more edit:

```
if (!isNaN(c[0]) && !isNaN(c[1]) && !isNaN(c[2])) {
  a.style.color = 'rgb('+c[0]+','+c[1]+','+c[2]+')';
}
```

This applies to that [code](http://www.bloggertipandtrick.net/2009/05/how-to-add-new-blogger-tag-label-cloud.html) and several variations.

Answer (score 0):

Your running into an IE7 specific bug.

Check this out:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4670

> Wow, nice bug. It's not a jQuery bug
>   though. You can reproduce it with bare
>   DOM functions:
>
> var li =
>   document.createElement("li");
>   li.value = "12";
>
> IE7 immediately
>   crashes in MSHTML.DLL trying to access
>   memory address 0x00000000. The same
>   crash happens with
>   li.setAttribute("value", "12"). Since
>   (in HTML4 at least) the value of an
>   < li> element only applies if it is a
>   child of an < ol> element, I suspected
>   it might be trying to access the
>   parent node. Sure enough, this does
>   not crash:
>
> var ol =
>   document.createElement("ol");   var li
>   = document.createElement("li");   ol.appendChild(li);   li.value = "12";
>   This bug seems to be fixed in IE8.

Comment: I tried using `appendChild` before setting the values but it made no difference, still your answer pointed to a real issue and led me on to the find the real cause (see bellow).